# How to define something?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to make a troubleshooting system however it comes up with an error saying issue is not defined. How do I correct this? Also could I continue with the array I'm using to add in more questions and answers e.g 4th could be `sound`?

```
def troubleshooting():
    print("Welcome to my phone troubleshooting system...")

problem = raw_input("Type the problem with the phone:")

problem = ['cracked', 'crack', 'broken']

if problem[0] in issue:
    print("Replace screen")
elif problem[1] in issue:
    print("Replace screen")
elif problem[2] in issue:
    print("Replace phone")
else:
    print("Replace screen")
```

Comment: You used `problem` twice; did you mean to use `issue` instead for the `raw_input()` result?

Comment: @MartijnPieters tbh i don't even know, what should i do? i suck at coding

Comment: @alexbwithtek I think you need to focus more on the tutorials and lesson plans you have at your disposal if you are feeling a bit overwhelmed with this task. If this is for a school assignment, maybe you should talk to your professor?

Comment: I will suggest you to start with [Python Tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/) and practice the basics of Python before starting to work on this code

Comment: @idjaw cant its half term and its due straight after, can you help below, now it only prints the same solution ffs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`issue` is not defined because you made a little mistake you put what the user typed inside `problem` instead of `issue` with that line : `problem = raw_input("Type the problem with the phone:")`

Comment: thanks it now works however it prints the same response everytime

Comment: def troubleshooting():


    print("Welcome to my phone troubleshooting system...")

problem = raw_input("Type the problem with the phone:")
 
problem = ['cracked', 'crack', 'broken']

if problem[0] in problem:
    print("Replace screen")
elif problem[1] in problem:
    print("Replace screen")
elif problem[2] in problem:
    print("Replace phone")
else:
    print("Replace screen")

Comment: when i type broken it still says replace screen when it should say replace phone wtf??

Comment: The mistake was located in the line I mentionned the rest was fine. `issue = raw_input(...` is what you should have.

Comment: ahhh yes, it works now. thank you so much bro

Comment: @alexbwithtek Please make sure you mark the answer as accepted (checkmark next to the answer).

Comment: @idjaw yeah, says i have to wait 2 mins, dw i got u bro